# Good software for recording podcasts on the Mac (OSX)

Tags: macos, mp3, podcasts, audio-recording

I'm looking for a piece of simple software that'll allow me to easily :

- Record Audio
- Perform basic editing (cut out a section, increase the volume)
- Save to MP3.

People talk about Audacity, but I find it a bit too complicated. Can any one recommend a lightweight and cheap Audio Recorder / Editor for OSX?

Comment: How important is the MP3?  Would you accept an answer that included an extra step of encoding with lame or iTunes?

Comment: It's important. I wanted to be able to create MP3 files immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [Amadeus Pro](http://www.hairersoft.com/AmadeusPro/AmadeusPro.html) easy to use.  It costs US$40.

Comment: Why to pay when you have already inbuilt GarageBand?

Answer (score 5):

GarageBand is another option. It's fairly easy to use and will let you do more sophisticated things as your needs increase.

[Podcasts in Garageband](http://www.apple.com/ilife/tutorials/#garageband-podcast)

Comment: Does it export to  MP3?

Comment: Yes, select "Export Song to Disk..." from the "Share" menu.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I now recommend officially Quicktime X if you got 10.6. It's blazing fast - Volume boost can't be done though.

OLD : [Fission by Rogue Amoeba Software](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/fission/) - BIG BIG ICONS. :)

Comment: Does Fission record audio?

Comment: No it doesn't. :| Quicktime X to take care of that part mayhaps? Wait wait... I just tried with Quicktime X... IT RECORDS AND TRIMS. :) Volume boost no though...

Comment: Quicktime Pro on Leopard records and allows edits, but does not do MP3.

Comment: Not an answer, but Quicktime for recording and editing, the Levelator for automatic leveling, and iTunes for conversion to MP3 is a very easy podcast workflow for Mac.

Comment: http://www.conversationsnetwork.org/levelator

Comment: Good Software Fission +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't use them, but try [Podcast Maker](http://www.lemonzdream.com/podcastmaker/) or [Podcaster](http://www.kudlian.net/products/podcaster/) for audio podcast or [Boinx TV](http://www.boinx.com/boinxtv/overview/) for video podcast.

Some people use [Wire Tap Studio](http://www.ambrosiasw.com/utilities/wiretap/).

Comment: podcast maker doesn't allow you to record, but it looks like it has a great interface for publishing podcasts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend [Sound Studio](http://www.freeverse.com/soundstudio/) by Freeverse.  It's a good all-around audio editor, with the standard bread-and-butter audio editing tools and also support for AU plugins if you need something special.  Also, it comes with a few [automation tools](http://www.freeverse.com/apps/app/?id=5012&view=goodies) to make publishing podcasting easier, such as adding intro/outro files, mastering for voice, etc.